# Disable forms authentication for specific IP

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

As of now I have forms authentication for some asp.net application. I want not to perform an authentication if IP is local, meaning 192.168.1.X. Is it possible to set up forms authentication in that way? Also what security issues could this bring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in your authentication page, that whether the request is from IP - 192.168.1.X or not. If the request is from IP - 192.168.1.X, then set the form authentication cookie & redirect to your default page.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but also I thought that allowed/denied IPs could be set in web.config